# Pentaho Transformation Executor not passing parameters successfully

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

Please refer to 2 Examples attached on this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16kzZGMi7-btr5nmSM4Yo8Kue4Z5P4lP-?usp=sharing)

Example1 : TEMP1.ktr & TEMP2.ktr 
Example2 : PARENT.ktr & CHILD.ktr

I am trying to pass few parameters to ktr patched in Transformation Executor and while having less number of field it is being able to pass those parameters successfully (Refer to Example1) but when i am increasing number of fields in the parent KTR it fails to send parameters to ktr patched in Transformation Executor (Refer to Example2)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the results are successfully transferred to CHILD.ktr. You can see the result with adding **"Get rows from result"->"Text file Output"** in CHILD.Ktr.

But if you want to see result in 'Write to log' step then you need to add all the result field as a parameter **one by one** in 'Transformation executor' step like you added for 'city' and 'state' in your **example1**.  Then show in log file like  ${tmp1} ...... ... as  a parameter.

You can download updated parent and child ktr

[Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yqa9BJ52qrjPUNOecgW8jhVplSMYNRAL?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for being so prompt. \n Please notice that child transformation only prints those 2 parameters values as Default values given to them in the Transformation properties, Parameter tab. \n It doesn't print the values which we pass through parent ktr.

Comment: I have updated my previous post to clear the things.